# Create an object from a class in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, oop

I just started programming in c++ and I don't understand why Xcode says that " Variable Type 'Rect' is an abstract class".. 
You can find a part of my code here: 
Thank you in advance for your help,

```
main(){
   Rect  r1(10,5,"R1");
return 0;
}
class Rect : public Figure
{
public:
  Rect(int l, int h,std::string Label) : Figure(l), _h(h),_Label(Label) {};
  ~Rect(){};
  std:: vector<std::string> toString() const;

protected:
    int _h;
    int _l;
  std::string _Label;
};

class Figure
{
public:
  Figure(int l):_l(l){}
  virtual std::vector<std::string> toStrings() const =0;
  virtual ~Figure();
protected:
  int _l;
};
```

Comment: this is standard error. It means that some pure virtual method was not implemented for class for which you are creating an object. In this case Rect must implement `std::vector<std::string> toStrings() const`.

Comment: `toString()` vs `toStrings() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard error. 
It means that some pure virtual method was not implemented for class for which you are creating an object.

In this case Rect must implement `std::vector<std::string> toStrings() const`. To fix it:

```
class Rect : public Figure
{
public:
  Rect(int l, int h,std::string Label) : Figure(l), _h(h),_Label(Label) {};
  ~Rect(){};
  std:: vector<std::string> toStrings() const override
  {
     return {};
  }

protected:
    int _h;
    int _l;
  std::string _Label;
};
```

Since C++11 there is `override` keyword which helps to spot such errors.